# Nginx and PHP-FPM doesn't work in vhost

Tags: nginx, php, gentoo

I am trying to move a project to Nginx + PHP-FPM with a virtual host. But when I try to load the website, I receive a file called 'download' with the contents of the index.php.

contents of nginx.conf:

```
user nginx nginx;

worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 64000;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log debug;

events {
        worker_connections 16000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {
        log_format main
                '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                '"$gzip_ratio"';

        access_log on;

        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        ignore_invalid_headers on;
        server_tokens off;

        keepalive_timeout 20;
        client_header_timeout 20;
        client_body_timeout 20;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        send_timeout 20;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        charset UTF-8;

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js image/x-icon image/bmp;

        server {
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.socket;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                }
        }
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

contents of the vhost file:

```
 server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name yps.dev;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/yps.access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/yps.error_log debug;

        root /home/bobbles/projects/yps_upstream/www/public;
        index index.cgi index.htm index.html index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.socket;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

The included fastcgi parameters:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf 

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

the PHP-FPM pool:

```
[www]
listen =/run/php-fpm.socket
listen.owner = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
user = nobody
group = nobody
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

the socket:

```
# ls -al /run/php-fpm.socket 
srw-rw-rw- 1 nginx nginx 0 Oct 12 22:12 /run/php-fpm.socket
```

In the access logs and the error logs, there is no output except a timeout in the error log:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error_log <==
2014/10/12 22:15:39 [info] 3317#0: *19 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2014/10/12 22:15:39 [info] 3317#0: *20 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

The access log is silent.

What am I doing wrong? `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` never gets created, so I assume that means that the request is never getting to php-fpm, but then what is wrong with my nginx config?

EDIT:

This is what happens when I try to access a static file from the directory:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log <==
2014/10/12 21:16:04 [error] 3021#0: *3 openat() "/usr/share/nginx/html/email.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /email.html HTTP/1.1", host: "yps.dev"

==> /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2014:21:16:04 +0200] "GET /email.html HTTP/1.1" 404 410 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36" "3.10"

==> /var/log/nginx/yps.error_log <==
2014/10/12 21:16:23 [info] 3021#0: *4 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

apparently the request is simultaneously being passed to the yps virtualhost, and not.

Comment: Close voters: please explain!

Answer (score 1):

this is an updated version of your vhost file that might work  :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yps.dev;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/yps.access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/yps.error_log debug;

        root /home/bobbles/projects/yps_upstream/www/public;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
        }

        location @handler { 
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.socket;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        }
}
```

Comment: @TomMacdonald could you please reset the `nginx.conf` , I see it had some changes , running the command `sudo nginx -T` can test the config for you and show you the error if there is any

Comment: sorry `sudo nginx -t` not captial letter

Comment: Yup I figured that out. :-) But there were no errors.

Comment: does the nginx serve static contents ?

Comment: see my edit. I tried to access a static fie that was in the vhost directory.